# CSS gradient transition_in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Do you have an idea to "transfer" this CSS Code to Javascript (maybe jQuery)?

```
html { background-color: #B94FC1; }
html:before, html:after { content: ""; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: fixed; z-index: -6; }
html:before { background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5856D6 0%, #C644FC 100%); animation: fgradient 5s linear 0s infinite alternate; }
html:after { background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #C643FC 0%, #FF5F37 100%); animation: sgradient 5s linear 0s infinite alternate; }
@keyframes fgradient { 0% { opacity: 1; } 100% { opacity: 0; } }
@keyframes sgradient { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/aMVBk/1/)

I want a transition from a gradient to an other. My own code works well, but I want try the same with Javascript ;)

Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: CAn you pls put your relevant code into the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using jquery:

**html**

```
<div class="gradient one"></div>
<div class="gradient two"></div>
```

**css**

```
html { background-color: #B94FC1; } 
body { margin:0; }
.gradient { content: ""; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: fixed; z-index: -6; }
.gradient.one { background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5856D6 0%, #C644FC 100%);}
.gradient.two { background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #C643FC 0%, #FF5F37 100%); display:none; }
```

**javascript**

```
$(function() {
    fadeToggle( $('.gradient.one') );
    fadeToggle( $('.gradient.two') );
});

function fadeToggle(el) {
    el.fadeToggle(5000,null,function() { fadeToggle(el); });
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aMVBk/2/